# Xero Rounding 'unitdp' parameter

Tags: php, xero-api

I used following code in xero API to generate an invoice. I want to know is this the correct way to pass 'unitdp' parameter with the request?

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Invoices?unitdp=4',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
        "Invoices":[
            {
                "Type":"ACCREC",
                "Contact":{
                    "ContactID":"'.$session->CONTACT_ID.'"
                },
                "LineItems":'.$lineItems.',
                "Date":"'.date("Y/m/d").'",
                "DueDate":"'.date("Y/m/d").'",
                "Status":"AUTHORISED",
                "Reference":"Stripe Payout"
            }
        ]
    }',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Accept: application/json',
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: Bearer '.$session->XERO_ACCESS_TOKEN,
    ),
));
```

I was trying to get rounded values but it didn't work. For an example if I have 54.54545454 I want 54.5454 in invoice

Comment: https://developer.xero.com/documentation/guides/how-to-guides/rounding-in-xero I assume the `unitdp=4` parameter means four decimal places. Seems like your call is correct.

Comment: You're doing the correct thing, according to the docs. When you say 'it didn't work', can you be more specific about the unexpected output you're getting?